# fullPage.js in HubSpot

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js, hubspot

I'd like to implement [Alvaro Trigo's fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) in a HubSpot website template. AFAIK, it's perfectly possible in a Custom HTML module, but can it be done in a more modular way? I've tried to assign the "fullpage" id and "section" classes to a "group" and "rich text" modules (the latter being direct children of the former), but it seems that fullPage doesn't scroll beyond the first "section". I'm guessing, that it's due to the fact that the "section" elements are not the direct children of the "fullpage" elements in the final HubSpot output, because of the extra elements that HubSpot adds. Is there a way to make a child module a direct child of the parent module in the output HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by assigning your script fullpage.js in following manner in Hubspot Coded files.

```
 <script src='{{ get_public_template_url("/path_to_your_js_in Hubspot/fullpage.js") }}'></script>
```

but keep in mind that the plugin supports are heavily depends on your HTML id's and classes.